Convert html to pdf using LWC
Is anyone here experienced converting your HTML file to PDF using LWC? I have a chart on the HTML file to display to the pdf so I chose LWC over VisualForce since Visualforce PDF rendering doesn’t support JavaScript-rendered content.
I've also used html2pdf but encountered: Lightning Web Security: Cannot access write..
Here's the flow:

The user will click the button and then will show the PDF-rendered page based on the HTML file.

I've tried this solution as well and it works but doesn't meet the requirements:

Upon click the button, it will clone the HTML elements open a new tab, and then calling the window.print() to print the cloned elements.

Thank you in advance for your help/assistance,
Max
